# ZFS pool created with ZFS on Linux, usable by SmartOS?

Tags: linux, zfs, smartos

I have a Linux server running libvirt + KVM which I am thinking of migrating to SmartOS. The server has a ZFS pool created with ZFS on Linux, where the KVM guests are stored (as ZVOLs). My question is, can this pool be usable by SmartOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

ZFS zpools are pretty portable... In your case, you'll want to make sure that the ZFS version on the destination system is greater-than or equal to the version of the system you're migrating from.

Of course, we're missing that information from your question...

You'll want to run `zpool upgrade -v` to obtain your version information.

See [Oracle's documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/bobn/entry/live_upgrade_and_zfs_versioning) and the [ZFS version Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Comparisons).

These days, SmartOS is at version 28 with *feature flags*.

Also see: [Can I trust that ZFS is consistent between Linux and FreeBSD?](https://serverfault.com/questions/417471/can-i-trust-that-zfs-is-consistent-between-linux-and-freebsd)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the links. Looks like my ZFS pool is also at version 28 with feature flags :)