# Problems migrating ZFS pool from Openindiana build 151a7 to FreeBSD 9.1

Tags: freebsd, zfs, import, openindiana

I'm currently running Openindiana on ESXi with RDM access to the 2 disks in my ZFS pool. I used to run Ubuntu with ZFS on Linux but since ESXi 5.1 supports my hardware I wanted to move away from that ZFS implementation to a native ZFS system.

I simply exported my ZFS pool, installed ESXi on a USB-stick and installed my OS's on a seperate SSD. I didn't have any problems importing the pool to Openindiana but for some reason Openindiana wanted to upgrade my pool, which is a bit weird since it already was v28 but I went ahead and did it anyway.

Now, a couple of months later, I want to give FreeBSD a go to test if there are any performance differences but here's when I'm running into issues. FreeBSD won't import my pool as it states it's a newer version, which I find odd since both Openindiana and FreeBSD use ZFS v5 and zpool v28.

This is what FreeBSD is telling me:

```
#zpool import
  pool: tank
  id: <ID>
  state: UNAVAIL
  status: The pool is formatted using an incomaptible version.
  action: The pool cannot be imported. Access the pool on a system running newer software, or recreate the pool from backup.
  see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-A5
  config:

       tank                                      UNAVAIL newer version
         mirror-0                                ONLINE
            gptid/<ID>                           ONLINE
            gptid/<ID>                           ONLINE
```

Of course, this would be expected if I tried to import the zpool to a system with an older version of ZFS but since the versions in FreeBSD and Openindiana allegedly are the same I don't understand why this is happening. I can import the zpool to Openindiana without any problems. What do you guys think is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of FreeBSD did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kworr pointed out, I was installing FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE which doesn't support zpool 5000 and that is why I can't migrate my ZFS pool.

Answer (score 3):

First, can you show the output of `zpool upgrade -v`?

Then see: [Can I trust that ZFS is consistent between Linux and FreeBSD?](https://serverfault.com/questions/417471/can-i-trust-that-zfs-is-consistent-between-linux-and-freebsd)

The pool version is 28, but "[Feature Flags](http://blog.delphix.com/csiden/files/2012/01/ZFS_Feature_Flags.pdf)" have been implemented to distinguish functionality between variants of ZFS on different platforms.

For instance, a `zpool get all vol1` on one of my ZFS on Linux systems ends with:

```
vol1  feature@async_destroy  enabled                local
vol1  feature@empty_bpobj    active                 local
vol1  feature@lz4_compress   active                 local
```

I understand that you're experimenting, but there's some benefit to sticking with a platform for awhile. OpenIndiana is probably newer than your FreeBSD target. Here's a [complete list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zfs#Comparisons) of versions and zpool compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Openindiana #zpool upgrade -v:
1  Initial ZFS version
*
*
28 Mutiple vdev replacements,

FreeBSD #zpool upgrade -v:
1  Initial ZFS version
*
*
28 Mutiple vdev replacements.

In other words, exactly the same. They should also run the same version according to the table you linked to which is why I thought it would work. I get what you're saying with sticking to the same system, but I wanted to learn more about FreeBSD but it looks like I'll be using Openindiana until I upgrade my server.

Comment: This feature set is common for the current FreeBSD testing branch. Latest 8.4 release also have this features and next 9.2 would receive them too.

Comment: @kworr So where do the OP's errors come from?

Comment: I think he tries to use zpool version 5000 (with feature flags) on FreeBSD 9.1, which only supports bare v28.

Comment: @kworr According to this page they should both be 5000:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS

Comment: @knorrhane Actually no, 9.1-STABLE (or actually this should be spelled as 9-STABLE) is a branch where 9.2 arrives anytime in the future. It's not the same as 9.1-RELEASE.

Comment: @kworr Alright, then I understand (and feel a bit stupid)! I wasn't reading it properly and I was indeed installing 9.1 RELEASE which doesn't support zpool 5000 as you say. That answers that, thanks for your help! According to the wiki-page FreeBSD 8.2 RELEASE supports ZPOOL 5000, maybe I'll try that or just wait to the 9.2 RELEASE. Anyway, thanks again!